# Accessibility checker issue with mapbox (mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib-inner)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

I am trying to troubleshoot and locate the following class:

**div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib-inner" role="list"**

On a WordPress site that I manage. We're using Mapbox for the office locations functionality, look & feel on the homepage. This is related to an accessibility checker issue that I cannot resolve so far. The suggestion from the checker is the following:

```
To solve this problem, you need to fix at least (1) of the following:
-Element has children which are not allowed: a[aria-label]
-Element uses aria-busy="true" while showing a loader
```

I've searched through the back end of the site, any source code while previewing the site, etc. and am unable to find **div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib-inner" role="list"** anywhere. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks